# Pyinstaller-created app crashes on a different computer

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I'm making a wxpython-based App for MacOS, and packaging it with pyinstaller. 
It seems to work on my machine, and on another machine, but crashes when I send it to my user.

I initially posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129747/macos-app-bundle-built-with-pyinstaller-crashes-on-another-mac, but then just tried to package a simple app and see if it would work, but the results are the same. I have Mac OS X 10.9.2, python 2.7.5, wxpython 2.9.5 and the latest development pyinstaller. The app did work on another machine, Mac OS X 10.9.3. However, when I sent it to my user who has Mac OS 10.8.5, the app crashes with Segmentation fault 11:

```
idm2277:~ mdutra$ /Users/mdutra/Desktop/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/test ; exit;
Segmentation fault: 11
logout

[Process completed]
```

Here is a simple script test.py that creates a hello window:

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None,wx.ID_ANY,"Hello!")
frame.Show(True)
control = wx.StaticText(frame,label = "Test successful!")
app.MainLoop()
```

And here is the specification my.spec, which I run as follows:

`python {path_to_pyinstaller_folder}/pyinstaller.py --windowed my.spec`

```
import os
src ='/Users/ojy/test'
dist = '/Users/ojy/test/bin'
icn = '/Users/ojy/icon.icns'

a = Analysis([os.path.join(src,'test.py')],
         pathex=[dist],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='test',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=None,
           upx=True,
           name='Test')
app = BUNDLE(coll,
         name='Test.app',
         icon=icn)
```

Any ideas why it happens and how to fix it?

Crash log (the complete file didn't meet the size limitation, so I replaced the middle chunk with ....), but I can add the whole thing if necessary.

```
Process:         test [9701]
Path:            /Users/USER/Desktop/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
Identifier:      test
Version:         0.0.0 (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [9698]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2014-06-09 17:13:40.558 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Report Version:  10

Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      D034FFD8-9A64-DFC6-DC85-9FD7B4DD8F61

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a40cd46 __kill + 10
1   test                            0x000000010f924c18 0x10f922000 + 11288
2   test                            0x000000010f937bed 0x10f922000 + 89069
3   test                            0x000000010f923454 0x10f922000 + 5204

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a40d6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91036f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91036ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91021191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a40dd16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92b67dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92b679ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a40d6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91036f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91036ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff91021191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000001  rcx: 0x00007fff502dcf28  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x00000000000025e5  rsi: 0x000000000000000b  rbp: 0x00007fff502dcf80  rsp: 0x00007fff502dcf28
r8: 0x0000000000000003   r9: 0x0000000035447f8c  r10: 0x00000000000fc080  r11: 0x0000000000000206
r12: 0x00007fff502ddd00  r13: 0x00007fa5d2c0e920  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000001
rip: 0x00007fff8a40cd46  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fa5d2c0f9a0
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
   0x10f922000 -        0x10f93eff7 +test (0.0.0 - ???) <C371E49E-CC99-3791-8965-4D3EE55AD3BF> /Users/USER/Desktop/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
0x7fff6f522000 -     0x7fff6f55693f  dyld (210.2.3) <6900F2BA-DB48-3B78-B668-58FC0CF6BCB8> /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff89c71000 -     0x7fff89dc3fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.9.2 - 1.9.2) <DC5F3D1B-036A-37DE-BC24-7636DC95EA1C> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x7fff89dc4000 -     0x7fff89e89ff7  com.apple.coreui (2.0 - 181.1) <83D2C92D-6842-3C9D-9289-39D5B4554C3A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x7fff89e8a000 -     0x7fff8a15bfff  com.apple.security (7.0 - 55179.16.1) <49A6A8FD-124D-30E0-94C3-C73F8C9469E6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x7fff8a335000 -     0x7fff8a35dfff  libJPEG.dylib (852) <4E159C31-1B41-3EFF-89EC-3F7BC9053F2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x7fff8a3be000 -     0x7fff8a3c4fff  libmacho.dylib (829) <BF332AD9-E89F-387E-92A4-6E1AB74BD4D9> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x7fff8a3c5000 -     0x7fff8a3e5fff  libPng.dylib (852) <CCBFA9A9-33C0-3189-AFE0-A77E831EEBA8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x7fff8a3fb000 -     0x7fff8a416ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.48.12) <4B7993C3-F62D-3AC1-AF92-414A0D6EED5E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x7fff8a417000 -     0x7fff8a43efff  com.apple.framework.familycontrols (4.1 - 410) <50F5A52C-8FB6-300A-977D-5CFDE4D5796B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
0x7fff8a43f000 -     0x7fff8a519fff  com.apple.backup.framework (1.4.3 - 1.4.3) <6B65C44C-7777-3331-AD9D-438D10AAC777> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
0x7fff8a51a000 -     0x7fff8a633fff  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.2.2 - 852) <1D023BCE-1FA2-3743-B449-7489BC0C5C43> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x7fff8a634000 -     0x7fff8a655fff  com.apple.Ubiquity (1.2 - 243.15) <C9A7EE77-B637-3676-B667-C0843BBB0409> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Versions/A/Ubiquity
0x7fff8a6e0000 -     0x7fff8a6e4ff7  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.5 - 94) <AAC003DE-2D6E-38B7-B66B-1F3DA91E7245> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x7fff8a6e5000 -     0x7fff8a73aff7  libTIFF.dylib (852) <0CA1662F-EB05-34DE-B9BA-0A03EC59B846> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
.....
.....
0x7fff93654000 -     0x7fff936d5fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 707.12) <69E3EEF7-8B7B-3652-8320-B8E885370E56> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x7fff936d6000 -     0x7fff93735fff  com.apple.AE (645.6 - 645.6) <44F403C1-660A-3543-AB9C-3902E02F936F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x7fff93754000 -     0x7fff93759fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30) <08F8731D-5961-39F1-AD00-4590321D24A9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x7fff937ef000 -     0x7fff93a24ff7  com.apple.CoreData (106.1 - 407.7) <A676E1A4-2144-376B-92B8-B450DD1D78E5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x7fff93a60000 -     0x7fff93abcff7  com.apple.Symbolication (1.3 - 93) <D5044687-E424-31CF-B120-667143E6B9C1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication
0x7fff93af0000 -     0x7fff93af4fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib (32.5) <DB009CD4-BB0E-3331-BBB4-A118781D193F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x7fff93af5000 -     0x7fff93af6fff  liblangid.dylib (116) <864C409D-D56B-383E-9B44-A435A47F2346> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x7fff93af7000 -     0x7fff93b95ff7  com.apple.ink.framework (10.8.2 - 150) <3D8D16A2-7E01-3EA1-B637-83A36D353308> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x7fff93fc9000 -     0x7fff94086ff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.8.0 - 4.8.0) <6CE333AE-EDDB-3768-9598-9DB38041DC55> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x7fff94087000 -     0x7fff94087fff  com.apple.vecLib (3.8 - vecLib 3.8) <6CBBFDC4-415C-3910-9558-B67176447789> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x7fff94088000 -     0x7fff940a7ff7  com.apple.ChunkingLibrary (2.0 - 133.3) <8BEC9AFB-DCAA-37E8-A5AB-24422B234ECF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/Versions/A/ChunkingLibrary
0x7fff940a8000 -     0x7fff944c5fff  FaceCoreLight (2.4.1) <DDAFFD7A-D312-3407-A010-5AEF3E17831B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/Versions/A/FaceCoreLight
0x7fff9453b000 -     0x7fff94541fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.5.2 - 2.5.2) <C713A35A-360E-36CE-AC0A-25C86A3F50CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x7fff9455e000 -     0x7fff94562fff  libpam.2.dylib (20) <C8F45864-5B58-3237-87E1-2C258A1D73B8> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
0x7fff94563000 -     0x7fff94566fff  libRadiance.dylib (852) <139962CD-21E2-3D31-9F47-D5F2D6C2C2BC> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x7fff94567000 -     0x7fff94589ff7  libxpc.dylib (140.43) <70BC645B-6952-3264-930C-C835010CCEF9> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x7fff9465e000 -     0x7fff946a8ff7  libGLU.dylib (8.10.1) <6699DEA6-9EEB-3B84-A57F-B25AE44EC584> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x7fff94eff000 -     0x7fff94efffff  libkeymgr.dylib (25) <CC9E3394-BE16-397F-926B-E579B60EE429> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x7fff94f00000 -     0x7fff94f0fff7  libxar.1.dylib (105) <370ED355-E516-311E-BAFD-D80633A84BE1> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
0x7fff94f4c000 -     0x7fff94f98ff7  libauto.dylib (185.4) <AD5A4CE7-CB53-313C-9FAE-673303CC2D35> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x7fff94fc1000 -     0x7fff94fc4ff7  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3) <F59367C9-C110-382B-A695-9035A6DD387E> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x7fff96120000 -     0x7fff9623892f  libobjc.A.dylib (532.2) <90D31928-F48D-3E37-874F-220A51FD9E37> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x7fff96239000 -     0x7fff96240fff  libGFXShared.dylib (8.10.1) <B4AB9480-2CDB-34F8-8D6F-F5A2CFC221B0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
0x7fff96241000 -     0x7fff96284ff7  com.apple.bom (12.0 - 192) <0BF1F2D2-3648-36B7-BE4B-551A0173209B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Versions/A/Bom
0x7fff962e1000 -     0x7fff962e2ff7  libdnsinfo.dylib (453.19) <14202FFB-C3CA-3FCC-94B0-14611BF8692D> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x7fff962e3000 -     0x7fff964cdff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.8 - 744.19) <0F7403CA-2CB8-3D0A-992B-679701DF27CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x7fff964ce000 -     0x7fff96580ff7  com.apple.LaunchServices (539.11 - 539.11) <A86F44E5-F285-3029-A5D1-00CD3C231A08> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x7fff96581000 -     0x7fff96978fff  libLAPACK.dylib (1073.4) <D632EC8B-2BA0-3853-800A-20DA00A1091C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x7fff96979000 -     0x7fff9697bfff  com.apple.securityhi (4.0 - 55002) <9B6CBA92-123F-3307-A2D7-D77A8D3BF87E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI

External Modification Summary:
    Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
        task_for_pid: 2
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
    Calls made by this process:
        task_for_pid: 0
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
    Calls made by all processes on this machine:
        task_for_pid: 4537
        thread_create: 1
        thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=142.6M resident=62.2M(44%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=80.4M(56%)
Writable regions: Total=67.3M written=236K(0%) resident=920K(1%) swapped_out=2728K(4%) unallocated=66.4M(99%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG shared images                    128K
CoreServices                       1360K
MALLOC                             41.5M
MALLOC guard page                    48K
Memory tag=242                       12K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              9752K
VM_ALLOCATE                        16.0M
__DATA                             10.2M
__IMAGE                             528K
__LINKEDIT                         52.1M
__TEXT                             90.5M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        19.0M
shared memory                       308K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             297.6M

System Profile:
Model: iMac13,3, BootROM IM131.010A.B07, 2 processors, Intel Core i3, 3.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.10f5
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF4), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.7f4 12974, 3 service, 21 devices, 3 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST500LM012, 500.11 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1d100000 / 2
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0x1d130000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x024f, 0x1d132000 / 9
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2412, 0x1d180000 / 3
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x1d181000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x828b, 0x1d181300 / 7
USB Device: Apple Optical USB Mouse, apple_vendor_id, 0x0304, 0x14400000 / 1
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1a100000 / 2
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8511, 0x1a110000 / 3
```